# WinForm Text Control that displays current character/character limit

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, label

I need a way to display, like you see in some web apps, the ***current characters/character limit*** for a `Text Control`(*i.e.* 3/500).  I usually see this as a `label` residing directly above or below the `Text Control`.

How is this 'normally' accomplished?  Should I override my `Text Control` somehow?  Do I just manually add labels by every `Text Control` and '`bind`' them to properties of the `Text Control`?  Do I need to create a composite control that has the T`ext Control` & `Label Controls` together to accomplish what I need?

Any direction or help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Attach a handler to `TextBox.TextChanged` and refresh the label based on `TextBox.Text.Length` and the maximum size you want to allow. You can also enforce the limit in the same handler by calling `TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text.Substring( 0, maxChars );`.

Comment: Just to clarify, this way I would be creating a label for each text control and an event handler for each text control as well?  I just want to make sure I am understanding correctly.  Thanks

Comment: However, only do that last part if the Length is greater than maxChars or you'll get an exception.

Comment: If you want, you can package this in a reusable `UserControl` so you only have to write the functionality once.

Comment: @Refracted - you could wrap the TextBox and Label in a UserControl.

Answer (score 1):

```
int maxChars = 100;

Textbox onKeyUp:
remainingChars.Text = Convert.ToString(maxChars - textbox.Text.Length);
```

Stick it in a function:

```
getRemainingChars(TextBox tb, Label lbl, int max)
{
lbl.Text = Convert.ToString(max - tb.Text.Length) + "/" + Convert.ToString(max);
}
```

Hopefully thats of some help

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are suggesting.  Is `remainingChars` a `Label`?  If so, shouldn't it be (maxChars - textbox.text.Length).

Comment: Ahh, the function part wasn't there when I commented.  So you would suggest manually adding labels by each text control and then using this function?  Sounds doable, thanks.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I got it the wrong way around. And yeah I think thats what I would do. :o) Oh and yes remainingChars is a label